# Format of writing authors in ieee format in overleaf

Tags: ieeeconf

I have four authors in my paper and I want the format of the authors as 3 authors in the first row and 4th author exactly below the 2nd author in the second row:

```
First Last 1              First Last 2              First Last 3
Affiliation 1             Affiliation 2             Affiliation 3
first1.last1@xxxxx.com    first2.last2@xxxxx.com    first3.last3@xxxxx.com

                          First Last 4
                          Affiliation 4
                          first4.last4@xxxxx.com
```

How can this be done in overleaf, I am able to get 2 authors in 2 rows but not in this format. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Formatting/writing authors is independent from editor (overleaf). You should inform us which document class you use, etc. The best way is to provide small, compilable document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`

Comment: Okay, thanks for letting me know. I am using documentclass{ieeeconf} and have resolved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP resolve the issue himself.

Comment: @Zarko Don't know if that changes anything, but since he accepted my answer, I would assume, he didn't solve it himself, but rather used the solution that I suggested.

Comment: @Max, I just repeat his claims:  "I ... and have resolved the issue." Well, if you right, that (s)he should (honestly) said, that problem is solved by your answer.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Actually I also myself got a solution and when I saw solution provided by @Max, that is also correct, tried the one given by him too. Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with a `tabular` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{l@{\hskip 1cm} l@{\hskip 1cm} l}
        First Last 1 &  First Last 2 & First Last 3\\
        Affiliation 1 & Affiliation 2 & Affiliation 3\\
        first1.last1@xxxxx.com & first2.last2@xxxxx.com & first3.last3@xxxxx.com\\
        \\
        & First Last 4 \\
        & Affiliation 4\\
        & first4.last4@xxxxx.com\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Note that the space between the columns can be adjusted using the argument of `hskip` and the space between two lines can be changed by adding another blank line or, if necesarry something like `vspace`.
The output here would look like this:

[image]